# Programming a 7 segment display based on push button

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

[image: Circuit diagram]

New to PIC programming or just programming in general. Wondering how I can display a number on the 7 segment display that corresponds to the number of times the push button at `RA5` is pressed. E.g press button 2 times = number `2` displayed and if it's pressed 10 times, the count resets to `0`. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Way too broad. Do you know how to write a basic blinking LED for starters?

Comment: How is it broad?

Comment: @TomEsther, in addition to being too broad, this question probably is better for the [Electronics Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) too.

Comment: Do you know how to read and write pins on the PIC?

Comment: @TomEsther, I rewrote my answer. Displays are an area of interest of mine so I decided to do some research and go above and beyond on this one anyway.

Comment: Who knows...maybe I'll write a programming book someday and come back and copy-paste or reference parts of my answer from here.

Answer (score 1):

### What do you mean this question is too broad?

Tom, first off, to help you out in the future:

According to the "closed" info. box on the question, this question was closed because it "needs to be more focused", and it should be updated "so it focuses on one problem only." I'd like to help you know what that means from my perspective.

I didn't vote to close it, but in this case *I totally understand why it was closed.*

It's too broad. You showed no coding attempt whatsoever and you asked what you thought was a very focused question, but which actually is too broad because there is too much to cover here. With you writing no code whatsoever, the questions within your question might include the following:

1. How do you write C at all?

   1. How do you set up a `main()` function?
   2. What's a function?
   3. What's a variable?
   4. What's a signed vs unsigned variable?
   5. How do you do bare-metal multi-tasking?
2. How do you program a PIC microcontroller?

   1. What are hardware registers and how do you use them?
   2. How do you configure pins as inputs vs outputs?
   3. How do you read pin states?
   4. How do you write to pins?
   5. How do you do bitwise operations to set an entire output port (all pins to the display) all at once instead of one-at-a-time?
3. How does electricity work?

   1. What does it mean to write a pin to output LOW vs ouput HIGH vs input?
   2. What's a pullup resistor?
   3. What's an LED array? How do you drive one?
   4. Are the LEDs in the 7-segment display turned on by writing the pin to output HIGH or output LOW (ie: do we need to source from or sink to the pins to light up the LEDs)?
4. How do displays work and how do you control them?

   1. I originally didn't see the circuit diagram until I edited the question to make the image show up, so I at first I also needed this information and thought we may need to cover the following:

      1. Does the 7-segment display have its own on-board driver IC and require I2C, SPI, or asynchronous RS-232-style TTL logic level Serial commands to drive it instead?
      2. How do displays work and how do you control them?
      3. What is [Persistence of Vision (PoV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision) and how might it apply?--in particular if driving multiple digits (multiple 7-segment displays)
      4. Do we need to consider multiplexing so you can control more 7-Segment digits with fewer pins?
      5. Do we need to consider Charlieplexing to use fewer pins still than standard multiplexing?

---

Anyway, let me get you started. The concept for your circuit is pretty straightforward.

### Here is how your circuit works:

1. Each segment on the display is turned on by setting the appropriate pin to output LOW, since Vcc (probably 5V) is connected to the other side of the LEDs. So, to turn on segment `a`, you'd set `RC0` to output LOW, to turn on segment `b`, you'd set `RC1` to output LOW, etc. Since all of your LEDs in this display share a common `Vcc` (usually 5V) pin, this is a *common anode* 7-segment display. Since each of the 7 LEDs in the display has its own dedicated pin, you can light up any of the LEDs at one time, rather than having to round-robbin through them in a multiplexed or Charliplexed fashion.

   1. If you wish to add another digit (another 7-segment display), you can double the number of required pins from 7 to 14, OR you can multiplex the new display, moving Vcc of each display to its own pin, and sharing the 7 segment pins `RC0` through `RE2`. Therefore, 2 displays can take 14 pins if not multiplexed, or 9 pins if multiplexed. OR, if you have a common-anode *and* a common-cathode 7-segment display, you can Charlieplex them, hooking up each individual LED together and the common anode of one display and the common cathode of the other display together on another pin, thereby getting away with only 8 pins for 2 displays--the *direction* of current would set which display gets lit up. Round-robbining through the displays to refresh them, thereby relying on our eyes' persistence of vision trait, would be required for both multiplexing and Charlieplexing.
2. You read the `RA5` button presses by seeing when `RA5`, an input pin, goes LOW. Since the button grounds the pin, and the pin has an external pullup resistor on it, HIGH means the button is NOT pressed, and LOW means it *is* pressed. Be sure to debounce this button press in software or else a single button press may register as dozens or even hundreds of button presses, depending on the mechanics of the button.

That's the circuit.

### Here is how the program logic works:

The logic is pretty straightforward too: each time you read a debounced button press, increment a counter. Output the digit on the 7-segment display according to the counter. Example: to write a `2`, you'd turn on segments `a`, `b`, `g`, `e`, and `d`. You can look at the display to figure out the other numbers.

### Sample source code outline to get you started:

```c
#include <stdbool.h> // For `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) macros in C
#include <stdint.h>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.

// Read the pin to look for button presses and return true if the 
// **debounced** button changes indicate the button has been pressed once
bool buttonWasPressedOnce()
{
    // you do this
}

// Write a number 0 to 9 to the display
void writeDisplay(uint8_t number)
{
    // you do this
}


// set up your PIC peripherals, input/output pin states, etc, here
void setup()
{
    // you do this
}

// your main program logic goes here; this runs repeatedly, forever
void loop()
{
    static uint8_t button_pressed_count = 0;
    if (buttonWasPressedOnce())
    {
        button_pressed_count++;
        // roll over after 9 back to 0
        if (button_pressed_count > 9)
        {
            button_pressed_count = 0;
        }
    }

    writeDisplay(button_pressed_count);
}

int main()
{
    setup();
    while (true)
    {
        loop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### References and additional reading, including sample libraries to look at:

1. Here is some Arduino code to get you started, to see various options. Port it to your PIC microcontroller: https://www.instructables.com/Different-methods-of-driving-7-Segment-LED-display/
2. Sample library to study as a reference: https://github.com/DeanIsMe/SevSeg
3. You'll also need to know button debouncing, and a ton of other skills. Example debouncing: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/Debounce

   1. my own debounce library I wrote for Arduino a long time ago: https://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/2014/05/ercaguybuttonreader-library-for-arduino.html and https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_ButtonReader and https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_EventReader
4. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/driving-led-arrays-with-an-arduino/
5. https://www.google.com/search?q=led+array&oq=led+array&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65.2207j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
6. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/13795

   1. great video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohewJ9sTfwM
7. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexed_display
8. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing
9. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic
10. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision
11. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display

Comment: Why do you need the hardware details? Each 7 segment display line is connected to a microcontroller port and lights up when a logic 1 is sent to it.

Comment: @TomEsther: is a "logic `1`" a pin HIGH or a pin LOW? That depends on the display. Does the 7-segment display have its own on-board driver and require I2C, SPI, or asynchronous Serial commands to drive it instead? (Your comment just answered that, but it was part of my original question).

Comment: pin HIGH. And I have no idea what you're talking about. I though this was a pretty straightforward question. I guess not

Comment: *I have no idea what you're talking about* But obviously that's not Gabriel's problem!  Everything he mentioned is hugely relevant to low-level microcontroller programming.  Definitely chase the three links posted in this answer, if only to get a flavor for things.

Comment: @SteveSummit I'm pretty sure the whole point of this platform was made to create a community that actually helps the "no idea what you're talking about" kind of people. Gabriel was willing to offer some help/guidance so I feel like it's partly his problem if I am unsure of it? That's just me though. I'll definitely check out the links

Comment: @TomEsther, can you be more specific when you say "I have no idea what you're talking about."? Also, can you edit the question to add your initial coding attempt? Do you know how to read the button pin, or write an LED pin? If so, can you ensure you include that in the code I'm asking you to add to your question?

Comment: I entirely rewrote this answer last night.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Sorry for the late reply but your comment was a huge help for me, thanks! Shame the question is currently closed